Is there an ASP.NET Core HealthCheck for Twilio?
There's a HealthCheck for SendGrid and a ton of other services.
But I can't find one for Twilio.
Is there one anywhere?

It looks like there is not a published package for Twilio health checks.
You may have to make your own health check, which luckily, isn't that hard.
Microsoft has some great docs on the process and Twilio has an exposed status endpoint and docs related to it.
Its a pretty simple process and well worth learning how to implement for future APIs as it increases API health visibility.

It's easy to create a health check that works in the ways I expect. However, writing one to the standards of Xabaril - that takes understanding Twilio and the HealthChecks system well. That takes time. I'll create something simple for my own use and hopefully someday soon Twilio will create a robust one. Thanks

WARNING - the forum link from Samuel Barnes is not to the Twilio support forum.
